# How to get rid of Indian spice smell in house?

Tags: cleaning, renovation

There is a house with strong Indian spice smell throughout. What could be the safest and most effective ways to get rid of such smell?

Comment: If you burn the house down, the resulting smell will mask the aroma of the spices.  :-)   Otherwise, the smell is a bit like cigarette smoke.  It's very hard to eliminate without stripping, sealing or replacing all of the surfaces that have absorbed it (floor, walls, ceiling, carpeting, cabinetry, etc.).  A thorough cleaning of all surfaces will help temporarily.  A simpler solution might be to sell the house to people who will be doing Indian cooking.

Comment: I am looking to buy one, and wonder how much work I or professional can do to eliminate it.

Comment: Like cigarette smoke, it permeates everything.  It clings to surfaces and is absorbed into porous surfaces.  Hard surfaces can be scrubbed.  Walls and ceilings can be cleaned, primed with a sealant, then painted.  Carpeting can be deep cleaned a few times but depending on the type of fiber, may need recurring applications of Febreze.  If the kitchen cabinets are wood, they may be tough to deal with.  You can try scrubbing them, then sealing the surface with paste wax.  Clean every fixture and appliance.  (cont'd)

Comment: Oven self-cleaning should get rid of anything inside, and stove fans can be disassembled for cleaning.  If hardwood floors still have a good coat of urethane, they may clean up, or can be refinished.  Hard floors like tile or laminate can be scrubbed.  Doors can be cleaned or cleaned and sealed like the walls or cabinets, depending on what they're made of.  (cont'd)

Comment: You will probably never completely get it out of the HVAC ductwork, but a professional duct cleaning will remove most of the dust odors may cling to.  There are deodorizers you can put in the ductwork.  An electrostatic air cleaner to replace the furnace filter will produce small amounts of ozone that will help.